# How we can get time of individual test cases in DejaGnu

Tags: testing, gcc, tcl, gnu

I am running GCC testsuite and I want to know time elapsed for each individual test case. GCC uses DejaGnu for its test suite and I know that `time` can be used in scripts to get the time of a test case. I am wondering if there is any flag that I can pass with `runtest` that forces timing for all test cases (without changing test scripts).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a generic way.

DejaGNU does not really have a built-in notion of the boundaries of a test.  For example, it's reasonably common for a single conceptual test to call "pass" or "fail" several times.  E.g., in GCC, a compilation test may check for several warnings from a given source file -- but each separate warning, and also the check for excess warnings, would be a separate pass or fail.  However, these would all arise from a single invocation of GCC.

I think there are two approaches that you can take.

1. You can hack the `.exp` files you care about and use knowledge of what they are doing to track the times you are interested in.
2. You can run a single `.exp` file in isolation and time how long it takes.  This is less useful in general, but it is what I did when making the GDB test suite more fully parallelizable.